# A good video to explain version control?

Tags: svn, version-control, video, cvs

Does anyone know where I can find a good video to explain version control to someone (mainly subversion)?

One that explains it in the simplest terms (like for someone who has never heard of version control before).

(not for me, its for a fellow coder)

Comment: Explain version control to someone in what position? Explaining to your CIO to invest in it? Explaining to fellow devs what the benefits are? Explaining to preschoolers?

Comment: @Welbog Okay so I'm explaining it to a 14 year old.  
@Evan No offense chief...

Comment: I think a really simple video that explains the concept is needed. Not a screen cast. This [twitter video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddO9idmax0o) is a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various videos on Version control:

**SVN:**

- [SVN & Version Control-Part 1 of 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hev1MdjP8Hs)
- [Best Practices for SVN](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfLLDg7zWQg)
- [SVN](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wYiabh2hpM)
- [How to Work with SVN](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhk7bdmVrng)

**GIT:**

- [Introduction to Git (Version Control System) under Windows](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwYKX9H8UcI)
- [Emerging Tech Talk #24 - Learning Git, Part 1 - Introduction to Version Control Systems](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLLkJ2rngk0)

Comment: So... be more specific, is that what are you asking for?

Comment: @alt Thanks alt!  I think Evan is gonna love this! :)

Answer (score 5):

only when I saw this 2 tutorials I finally knew what and how version control worked ...

> [A Visual Guide to Version Control](http://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-version-control/)

and

> [Intro to Distributed Version Control (Illustrated)](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intro-to-distributed-version-control-illustrated/)

from reading this to master it, was very quick! :)